# Why is a certain string added to the end of the message in steganography

Tags: python, steganography

I am trying to learn steganography and how it is implemented. I looked into some code on [Github](https://github.com/f0rum/Cryptography-HIde-Text-in-Image-by-Python-Script-/blob/master/Crypter.py), but I couldn't understand the following part of the code:

```
def hide(filename, message):
    img = Image.open(filename)
    binary = str2bin(message) + '1111111111111110'
    if img.mode in ('RGBA'):
        img = img.convert('RGBA')
        datas = img.getdata()

        newData = []
        digit = 0
        temp = ''
        for item in datas:
            if (digit < len(binary)):
                newpix = encode(rgb2hex(item[0],item[1],item[2]),binary[digit])
                if newpix == None:
                    newData.append(item)
                else:
                    r, g, b = hex2rgb(newpix)
                    newData.append((r,g,b,255))
                    digit += 1
            else:
                newData.append(item)    
        img.putdata(newData)
        img.save(filename, "PNG")
        return "Completed!"

    return "Incorrect Image Mode, Couldn't Hide"
```

As you can see, the author has added the string `'1111111111111110'` when converting the message (text) into a binary string. Why did he do this and why are all of them 1s except the last bit, which is 0?

Answer (score 1):

It's a marker. They are used to mark either the beginning or the end of a section in your stream. In this case, you could call it an [end-of-message (EOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_of_message) marker, in that it lets you know when to stop reading more bits.

The choice of the marker value depends on the data it's used with. In this case, the author has made the assumption that the message will be a string of the usual letters and punctuation symbols, i.e., he doesn't expect any extended ascii codes (128-255). Since these codes aren't expected to show up in the message, he chose a concatenation of 255 and 254 to be his marker.

You can fool this system by hiding the message `'abc\xff\xfedef'` (`'\xff'` and `'\xfe'` are just string values for the ascii codes 255 and 254). The extraction, upon coming across those values, will interpret them as the EOM signal and stop. Therefore, you will only get back `'abc'`. More sequences can have the same effect, such as the string `'_\xff\xc4'`.

```
01011111 11111111 11000100
   |  <-- this -->  |
```

Here we would end the extraction process prematurely after having retrieved only 3 bits. Depending on how the decoder is prepared to translate those bits to a message string, it can either raise an error or return complete garbage.

Generally speaking, you can use a marker to signal the beginning/end of a section when you can guarantee that this sequence will not be found anywhere else before the appearance of the marker itself. If you can't guarantee that, a viable option is to add a few bits at the beginning the section ([header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header_(computing))) to tell you how long your bit stream is going to be.